# Linq to Entities Multiple Includes but just select one relation

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following Linq (lambda) expression:

```
public IEnumerable<SetupShift> GetEmployeeShift(int employeeId)
        {
            var shifts = DbContext.Set<Employee>()
                .Include(em=> em.SetupShiftCode.SetupShifts)
                .Where(em=> em.EmployeeId == employeeId)
                .Select(em => em.SetupShiftCode.SetupShifts).ToList();

            return shifts;
        }
```

An Employee has a ShiftCode (description), and a ShiftCode has many SetupShifts (collection of days with Intimes, etc).

I want to return only SetupShifts but when I mouse over ToList(); the result is `List<ICollection<SetupShifts>>` instead of only `List<SetupShifts>`.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`.

```
var shifts = DbContext.Set<Employee>()
            .Include(em=> em.SetupShiftCode.SetupShifts)
            .Where(em=> em.EmployeeId == employeeId)
            .SelectMany(em => em.SetupShiftCode.SetupShifts).ToList();
```